# iOS library to measure image similarity

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, image-processing

I'm looking for an objective-c library (for iOS) that can calculate the similarity between two images (dssim, perceptual/average hash etc).
I have a basic knowledge of how to build it but I really don't want to re-invent the well, so if there's something out there I'd rather use it/adapt it for my scope that re-write everything.

Answer (score 2):

You can use OpenCV for this. Just google "iphone image comparison OpenCV". You will find many links.

This one is very good for measuring similarity : http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FastMatchTemplate

Comment: I think you definitely want to go for opencv. One of the best IP library currently, and available on many different platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already tested OpenCV - it's close to what I want but not perfect. FastMatch returns only YES/NO based on similarity - I need a percentage of similarity for images that have been slightly modified. I was looking for something more like the [Image comparison SDK](https://sites.google.com/site/imagecomparison/) from Brett Spurrier  but the site seems dead (I tried writing to Brett but no answer)